# How to send values using labels of a field in Protractor

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, protractor, element

Can anyone please guide me on how can I send values using the labels of the field. I'm aware of the fact that one should not send values using labels as the labels changes but in my case it's not that case, i.e it's not gonna change.
I'm attaching the HTML Code screenshots of that label and the webpage screenshot as well. [WebPage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWYu9.jpg) and the [HTML Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFItU.jpg).
The only code structure I can show is in this image.[Code Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlVqw.jpg)

The codes which I have tried are as below,
The From Date and To Date is one set of code I tried. So, like first From and To Date variable is one way of implementation of code, second set is some other way of implementing the code and so on.

```
async selectDates(FromDate:string,ToDate:string){
   console.log("$$$ From and To Date in selectDates function From: "+FromDate+" To: "+ToDate);
   // var fromDate = "From Date";
   // await browser.element(by.xpath("//label[. = '" + fromDate + "']/following-sibling::input"));
   // await fromInput.sendKeys(FromDate);

    
    // var toDate = "To Date";
    // await browser.element(by.xpath("//label[. = '" + toDate + "']/following-sibling::input"));
    // await toInput.sendKeys(ToDate);

    // var TmpLabelName = "From Date";
    // var TmpInput = await element(by.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'" + TmpLabelName + "')]/following-sibling::input"));
    // await TmpInput.sendKeys(FromDate);

    // var TmpLabelName2 = "To Date";
    // var TmpInput2 = await element(by.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'" + TmpLabelName2 + "')]/following-sibling::input"));
    // await TmpInput2.sendKeys(ToDate);

    // var TmpLabelName = "From Date";
    // var TmpInput = await element(by.xpath("//label[.,'" + TmpLabelName + "']/following-sibling::input"));
    // await TmpInput.sendKeys(FromDate);

    // var TmpLabelName2 = "To Date";
    // var TmpInput2 = await element(by.xpath("//label[.,'" + TmpLabelName2 + "']/following-sibling::input"));
    // await TmpInput2.sendKeys(ToDate);

    // let FlabelName = "From Date";
    // var Finput = await element(by.xpath("//label[. = '" + FlabelName + "']/following-sibling::input")).sendKeys(FromDate);

    // let TlabelName = "To Date";
    // var Tinput = await element(by.xpath("//label[. = '" + TlabelName + "']/following-sibling::input")).sendKeys(ToDate);

    
}
```

I have searched for many articles and other answers but neither of them gave the desired answer. can anyone please help me with this, It would be really helpful!!

Edits:
The Code structure (Sorry for identation issues)

```
function ele(label: string){

return element.all(by.css('td > label.fieldlabel')).filter((ele)=>{

   return ele.getText().then((text: string) => {

      return text === label;

   });

}).get(0);
```

}

```
export class Reports extends ReportObjects {


                         async selectDates(FromDate:string,ToDate:string){

                                       await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + FromDate + "';", ele('From Date'));

                                       await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + ToDate + "';", ele('To Date'));

                        

                         }

          async generateReport(testDataRow:number){

                                       let fromDate = excel.getColumnValue('FromDate',testDataRow).toString();

                                       let toDate = excel.getColumnValue('ToDate',testDataRow).toString();

                                      

                                       await this.selectDates(fromDate,toDate);

                        

                         }


 }
```

The Excel Screenshot [From/To Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo9FW.jpg)

PS: I cannot use ID because that is dynamic, it's changing for different scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution with java script executer

```
     const FromDate= //your from date
      function ele(label: string){ 
           return element.all(by.css('td > label.feildlabel').filter((ele)=>{
              return ele.getText().then((text: string) => {
                 return text === label;
              });
           }).get(0);
        }
        await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + FromDate + "';", ele('From Date'));
```

Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But, this gives me the following error ------>  NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [label="From Date"]>input)

Comment: Hi Madhan, Now, I'm not getting any No element error. But the value of FromDate is not getting inserted. It's appearing to be blank though the variable has values.

Comment: @ShahbazKhan please provide the date in expected format. For more visibility update the Question with your code

Comment: Hi @Madhan PLease check now and let me know

Comment: @ShahbazKhan move `ele` funtion to your `Reports ` class

Answer (score 0):

Even we not recommend to use XPATH, but in your case we need it.

```
cost ele = element(by.xpath('//label[text()="From Date"]/../../input'))
await ele.sendKeys(FromDate)
// if sendKeys() can't work, try as below
await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", ele, FromDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting no such element error.I'm not able to figure out what is the case.